# Exposing AWS MSK cluster using own domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-msk

I am facing an issue with exposing AWS MSK stack - to be more precisely:
case of our development process is to deliver for a client, static, publicly accessible domains for MSK brokers (it is a MUST HAVE, because we are including SSL certificates in packages, that are distributed for clients and used for producing Kafka messages, so if the domain name is changed, which we would like to avoid, a lot of client packages need to be generated and redistributed again).
Amazon offers only 1 option for enabling public access to MSK from Internet - exposing brokers.
This is quite problematic because if something unexpected happens with the whole stack and it will be redeployed, the broker's DNS will be changed and we need to perform activities with the client packages, described above.

I have tried some solutions, for example here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/how-goldman-sachs-builds-cross-account-connectivity-to-their-amazon-msk-clusters-with-aws-privatelink/
but I can't get with the SSL traffic (different certificates & DNS on load balancer won't "talk" with brokers).
Have you any idea how to deal with it and publicly expose brokers by using different DNS names & SSL/TLS traffic?

Answer (score 1):

Both [this blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/secure-connectivity-patterns-to-access-amazon-msk-across-aws-regions/) and the one you mentioned describe the pattern of exposing MSK broker(s) via a network load balancer (NLB).  You can [attach](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/use_cases/nlb_tls_termination/) an SSL cert generated by AWS ACM to the NLB and then create an Alias DNS record on Route 53 (or CNAME on an external DNS) to point to your NLB, which should solve your problem.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I've done the setup below:

- NLB & TLS listener (on port 9094) with a certificate generated & signed with AWS PCA (in example: *.xyz.kafka.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com)

- Target group attached to NLB & pointing to one of the broker's IP (port 9094) address

- modified advertised listeners on the tested broker (added: CLIENT_SECURE://b-2.xyz.kafka.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:9094)

- on my localhost, I created host entry which pointing custom domain to loadbalancer IP (b-2.xyz.kafka.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com -> NLB_IP)

Comment: But when I am trying to produce message to a topic, I am still getting:


ERROR [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (b-2.xyz.kafka.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/xxx:9094) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Comment: I don't think custom DNS names are yet supported with MSK. You can setup a VPC endpoint but that won't get you kafka.mycompany.com like DNS name.  It seems this feature is in the list of enhancements for MSK.

Answer (score 1):

I created a ticket with AWS asking the same question and they came back with the answer that it is not possible to associate a DNS name with brokers if anything other than plain text authentication is used.

Following is their response:

---

From the case notes I understand that you want to use custom domain name for your MSK broker in cluster "xyz-dev-cluster" in "us-east-1" region instead of the bootstrap server name.

Please correct me if I misunderstood your query in any way.

From the backend I can see that you're using SASL/SCRAM authentication method. Please allow me to mention that unfortunately, using custom DNS with MSK cluster is limited to plain-text authentication. This is because TLS in-transit encryption is not supported when using a Custom DNS for the Broker endpoints. The public TLS certificates deployed on the MSK Brokers are signed for the "kafka..amazonaws.com" domain which is not the same as the Custom DNS and hence the TLS handshake would fail. This is applicable for all the encrypted authentication methods including IAM, mTLS and SASL/SCRAM whether ther cluster is private or public.

I apologies for this limitation due to the service design and inconvenience caused due to this issue.

Comment: AWS mentioned that this feature viz. Supporting custom domain names is a requested feature that has not been worked on yet.